# Why IPrincipal.IsInRole parameter is a String?

Tags: c#, .net

I´m implementing the `IPrincipal` interface and the fact that the `role` parameter is a `String` sounds strange to me. I guess that there are good reasons for that, but I want to know why.

Comment: Since you think it's strange, you must have some other type in mind that you must think is more logical. Care to share it?

Comment: More than thinking about some other type, it was just I try to avoid magic strings and if I have to use one, I want to know why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because roleprovider is a pluggable section of the authentication, so you can roll your own (pun intended) and provide the results for a user's role membership.

If you imagine that a role based authentication mechanism needs to have any number of named roles then this would not be so easy if this was based on some typed or hard coded system. So using a string to match against roles stored in some way actually works out ok.

P.S. The asp.net membership and authentication system is a mess overall and is about to get a major upgrade in the upcoming MVC5 and Asp.Net update using the owin pattern.

Comment: +1 Just for the pun :D (And also for a good answer)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the implementation for determining roles across API's (e.g. Windows or Novell) is quite different. However, one common denominator is that there are group names, and a `string` is the right type for that.

See, under the hood, `IsInRole` can have many different implementations. Some of which query Active Directory.